# Entering multiple image on single page using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layouts, arcgis-9.2

I have 10 dynamic images.

I want to print these images (10) on a single layout page.

How to do this using ArcGIS 9.2?

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention if these images are geo-referenced.

1. create a separate data frame for each and place them manually on a layout.

Comment: @Sunny, make sure you position each data frame within the layout so they are not overlapping.